# "Manifest parsing has failed" when installing teams apps from App Studio

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I haven't been able to install any applications I create using App Studio since yesterday afternoon (Oct 5 Us/New_York time). When I try to install directly from App Studios I get a "Manifest parsing has failed" error message. If I download the package and try to upload it to the team I get a generic something went wrong error message.

Im having this issue with all my applications including those I haven't made any changes to.

I am running Microsoft Teams Version 1.3.00.24758 and App Studio version Version 1.5.1
App studios is setting the manifest's to version 1.8

I have the same issue when I run teams in developer preview.

On a side note: I notice that App Studio now has the option to create a Team tab for a Meeting. Which I believe is in preview right now and not officially out. I don't remember seeing that earlier in the day. Maybe App Studio was recently updated?

Comment: I am having the same issue with Teams v1.3.00.23764 (and AppStudio 1.5.1). This seems like a regression bot-service since I have not updated Teams or App Studio recently.

Comment: The very next question on this site under "Teams" seems to be experiencing the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228173/ms-teams-bot-deploy-rejects-auto-generated-manifest-json . Sounds like an issue with Teams or App Studio. If so, you can try manually uploading the manifest to your internal company store.

Comment: I checked this for multiple teams ring (Public, GCC, Dev, R1, R2, R3,R4) App studio version is updated to 1.5.1 but create app through app studio gives the manifest version to 1.7 not 1.8, could you please try to set the manifest version to devPreview. I'm running Microsoft Teams Version 1.3.00.27930 (64-bit)

Comment: App studios is no longer using version 1.8. I also had to remove a context section under  configurableTabs from the manifest. 

Everything seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Teams bot deploy rejects auto-generated manifest.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228173/ms-teams-bot-deploy-rejects-auto-generated-manifest-json)