# Attempt to install new bot apps for Teams yields generic error "Manifest Parsing has Failed"

Tags: microsoft-teams

Working with a new Microsoft Teams App (a Bot, built with the MS Bot Framework, and deployed to Azure).  Whether using the soon-to-be-deprecated App Studio, or the soon-to-replace-it Preview of the Developer Portal, attempting to install directly or to download the manifest and sideload to teams, in every case the following image is displayed:
[image]

The message "Manifest parsing has failed" is quite unhelpful.  I am mystified that Microsoft is not supplying some additional information about WHAT failed.  Is there a log file somewhere that I can find the actual problem?

UPDATE RESPONDING TO COMMENTS:
One kind commenter pointed me to a similar SO question, but the suggested solution (setting manfestVersion from that currently generated at 1.9 to 1.7) did not work.  Behavior was identical.

Another commenter asked me to provide the manifest scrubbed of identifying information.  Here it is:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifestVersion": "1.9",
    "id": "VALID-GUID",
    "packageName": "com.package.name",
    "name": {
        "short": "Stephan Trial App",
        "full": ""
    },
    "developer": {
        "name": "Valid Company",
        "mpnId": "Correct mpnId",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.thiscompany.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.thiscompany.com/legal/privacy-policy/",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.thiscompany.com/legal/terms-of-use/"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Stephan's App's Short Description",
        "full": "Stephan's App's Longer Description"
    },
    "icons": {
        "outline": "outline.png",
        "color": "color.png"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "VALID-CORRECT-GUID",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "personal"
            ],
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "supportsFiles": false
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "SAME-VALID-CORRECT-GUID-AS-BOT-ABOVE",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "CmdID",
                    "type": "query",
                    "title": "Command Title",
                    "description": "Command Description",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "fetchTask": false,
                    "context": [
                        "commandBox",
                        "compose",
                        "message"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "ParmID",
                            "title": "Parameter Title",
                            "description": "Parameter Description",
                            "inputType": "Text",
                            "choices": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "messageHandlers": []
        }
    ],
    "validDomains": [],
    "devicePermissions": [
        "geolocation"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Teams bot deploy rejects auto-generated manifest.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228173/ms-teams-bot-deploy-rejects-auto-generated-manifest-json)

Comment: Can you post a copy of the manifest (remove any private things you might want to).

Comment: Thanks @TylerH - so appreciate the pointer.  Sadly the suggested fix did not work.

Comment: Thanks @HiltonGiesenow - scrubbed manifest now in the edited question.

Comment: Remember that the MS Teams channel must be enabled for the bot in Azure. This has gotten me a few times when I'd forgotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Within `composeExtensions > commands > parameters` you have `inputType` but it's set to 'Text' (capital T) which is invalid - it needs to be 'text' (small 't'). Try that and it should be fine.

Comment: My gratitude to you, thanks.  Weirdly I didn't render that inputType to "Text" with a capital T.  That was done by both App Studio and Developer Preview.  Oy.  And of course one wonders why Microsoft is unable to provide an error that says something like "Invalid value for inputType" or something.  But Thanks.

Comment: That is strange. Might be a bug in developer preview. If it helps you or others, I saw the bug in two places (I tried both to confirm) - in Visual Studio Code it highlighted it as a syntax error, and when I tried to upload the final app (manifest + two sample icons) to App Studio is told me straight away that it was that value that was a problem.